# update meta property dynamically from the script tag in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am working on one project where i need to use html viewport content property interactive-widget but as that is only available in chrome and Firefox so i need to do something which can append that property only if user agent is not safari so how i can achieve this.

Note:- I am also using webpack.

```
  plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'web/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            splashLogo: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `../../assets/images/new-ify${mapEnvToLogoSuffix(envFile)}.svg`), 'utf-8'),
            usePolyfillIO: platform === 'web',
            isStaging: envFile === '.env.staging',
        }),
```

```
 </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
    <script>
        if (window.safari === undefined) {
            var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
            viewport.content += ', interactive-widget';
        }
    </script>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" id="favicon" href="/favicon.png">
    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.usePolyfillIO) { %>
        <!-- polyfill.io is only needed on Web to support older browsers. It should not be loaded for desktop -->
        <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default%2CResizeObserver&flags=gated"></script>
    <% } %>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
</head>
```

in above code i am checking if window. Safari is undefined then contact he content string but that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can utilize the userAgent property of the navigator object in JavaScript to discern the type of browser. By implementing this snippet, you can readily detect the user's browser; if it is not Safari, you will accomplish your desired outcome.

```
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial- 
scale=1"
/>
<script>
  var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  if (!isSafari) {
    var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if (viewport) {
      viewport.content += ", interactive-widget";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
    <script>
        var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        if (!isSafari) {
            var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
            if (viewport) {
                viewport.content += ", interactive-widget=resizes-content";
            }
        }
    </script>

above is the code which i am getting after page reload so it's definitely not adding any property in chrome as well

Comment: but when i check viewport variable in console once page is loaded it is showing the result as expected so maybe it's because script is being loaded after page is rendered so maybe i need some solution which works at compile but that is also not possible